# Ajax fade in new results from MySQL

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a system similar to FaceBook where posts are updated automatically from a table in MySQL. At the moment, it just refreshes the div every 10 seconds. Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var auto_refresh = setInterval(
        function(){
            $('#refresh').load('index.php?_=' +Math.random()+' #refresh').fadeIn("slow");
        }, 10000);
</script>
```

I would like the div to be updated only if there is a new row in the MySQL table, and the new result to fade in.
Is there is a way to do this? I have searched everywhere, and tried everything, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: did you search for push notifications in conjunction with ajax?

Comment: I have, and can't find anything...

Answer (score 1):

google long polling is the way to go do research about it for whatever language you are using for your serverside programming. I am using java and comet api.

Comment: Well without IE there would be the great Web Socket API but... :-/

Comment: I did try, butI can't find it. I just want the div to update if there is something new in the database.

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to do it. If anyone has the same problem, here is what I used:

```
var cacheData;
var data = $('#refresh').html();
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function ()
{
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data) {
            if (data !== cacheData){
                //data has changed (or it's the first call), save new cache data and update div
                cacheData = data;
                //$('#refresh').fadeOut("slow").html(data).fadeIn("slow");
                //$('#refresh').fadeOut("slow").load('index.php?_=' +Math.random()+' #refresh').slideDown("slow");
                $('#refresh').fadeOut("fast");
                $('#refresh').load('index.php?_=' +Math.random()+' #refresh');
                $('#refresh').fadeIn("slow");
            }           
        }
    })
}, 1000);
```